# Web API Notification using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web, push-notification, web-push

I am looking at creating Notification in Google Chrome, using Spring Boot. The notification is nowadays common on all sites.

The Spring Boot Admin module does create the same notification if the client application monitored goes down or comes up.

Can some help me with the same, very less support on the internet for the same? Even if the concept is clarified I can share a sample code for Spring boot and make it public via git. Else if a working sample help will also be appreciated.

We have JS way of creating the same, using new Notification('Title',) and window.webkitNotifications.createNotification.

Comment: Chrome doesn't run java, your application would need to return javascript to do it with the page.

Comment: So is it done via javascript in web sites, I thought we have to call and register a notification channel on the browser. So how to do this, or any idea how it is done?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it using 2 parts.

Server-Sent-Events (sse) emitters with Spring boot and Notification Web APIs

Adding the sample code [here](https://github.com/ameya/ssedemo)

Hope it helps someone looking for a similar solution.

Comment: There is some cross site cooke issue with the URL , if you can make the application https will work

Comment: what are the frameworks that you are using? did you only used WebSocket or did you use something else